# Can't Change the default python 3.5 to 3.7 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, configuration, python3

I am running ubuntu 16.04. Recently I have installed python3.7.3 by running these commands:

```
sudo apt update



sudo apt install software-properties-common



sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa

sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python3.7
```

after running these commands I typed:

```
python3.7
```

it says:

> Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 26 2019, 01:59:45)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on
>   linux Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
>   information.

But the default python in ubuntu still is python3.5.
To configure it I am ran the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

the output of the command is as follows:

> There is only one alternative in link group python (providing
>   /usr/bin/python): /usr/bin/python3.5 Nothing to configure.

Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems generally a bad idea to change the Python where the system depends on, as I experienced it. In short, gnome-terminal did not start any more, and I could not solve it for my Ubuntu 18.04. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218562/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg](this thread) for details.
I ended up reverting the changes to the alternatives, and used Python3.8 for the application only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After install Python 3.6.x and/or 3.7.x you need to make python3 use the new installed python instead of the default 3.5 release.

Run following commands to add the alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 2

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 3
```

Then you can switch between the python versions for python3:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

> **BUG:** There is a bug for this method: gnome-terminal won’t launch after switch to newer version.

To solve this, you need to recreate the symlink:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3

sudo ln -s python3.5 /usr/bin/python3
```

Check version with:

```
python3 -V
```

Comment: To avoid the error, you can use an alias:
    alias python3='/usr/bin/pytho3.6'
Then re-login and check version:
    python --version